getSignedUrl unsafe return of any type
I am trying to create a signed url using the aws sdk, but I keep getting this type error.
Here's my code:
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';

const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: 'auto',
    endpoint: `https://${process.env.R2_ACCOUNT_ID!}.r2.cloudflarestorage.com`,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.R2_ACCESS_KEY!,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.R2_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
    },
});

export async function getDownloadUrl(fileName: string) {
    return await getSignedUrl(
        s3Client,
        new GetObjectCommand({
            Bucket: process.env.R2_BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: fileName,
        }),
        { expiresIn: 3600 },
    );
}

I've tried the following without any sucess:
return await getSignedUrl<GetObjectCommandInput, GetObjectCommandOutput>(
        s3Client,
        command,
        { expiresIn: 3600 } as RequestPresigningArguments
    );

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!
Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
(alias) getSignedUrl<ServiceInputTypes, GetObjectCommandInput, GetObjectCommandOutput>(client: Client<any, ServiceInputTypes, MetadataBearer, any>, command: Command<...>, options?: RequestPresigningArguments | undefined): Promise<...>
import getSignedUrl


I have added an image to the main post

I've added the error as code, and removed the image

Thanks. Now hopefully someone who knows about typescript-eslint can verify if this is reproducible and what the best way to deal with it might be. I'm not that person so I'll disengage. Good luck!

You are not adding all types: I have just added an example of function return type as Promise: This indicates that the getDownloadUrl function returns a promise that resolves to a string
Error "Unsafe assignment of an any "  means that "returned value" or "another values" are being type of any because you have not mentioned any type and that is not allowed. So add all types, return types.
Just try this once, I have made few modifications.
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand, GetObjectCommandInput } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';

const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: 'auto',
    endpoint: `https://${process.env.R2_ACCOUNT_ID!}.r2.cloudflarestorage.com`,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.R2_ACCESS_KEY!,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.R2_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
    },
});

export async function getDownloadUrl(fileName: string): Promise<string> {
    const command: GetObjectCommandInput = {
        Bucket: process.env.R2_BUCKET_NAME!,
        Key: fileName,
    };

    return await getSignedUrl(
        s3Client,
        new GetObjectCommand(command),
        { expiresIn: 3600 },
    );
}

